# Minesweeper code opening the zero boxes without max recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, minesweeper

I am making Minesweeper in Python. I have all of the code done and working, but one feature I would like to add is that when you open a tile with zero mines nearby, it opens all of the squares around it. The problem stems from the fact that if any of the boxes I open are also zero, they also need to open all of the boxes around them. I believe I have a function to do this, but the max recursion depth is always reached. I tried raising the limit to probably higher than I should have, but I still got the error. I was wondering if their was a different way to do this without so much recursion. Thanks for any help, here is my current code:

```
def open_zero(x):
    # For opening the boxes with no nearby mines
    # First, opens the box the user clicked on
    button_list[x].config(bg="#90949b")
    # Then opens all nearby boxes through the box_open function
    # I need to run these values through the function so that if they are
    # zero, they will open all nearby tiles as well.
    # This causes too much recursion.
    box_open(x+1)
    box_open(x-1)
    box_open(x+width)
    box_open(x+width+1)
    box_open(x+width-1)
    box_open(x-width)
    box_open(x-width-1)
    box_open(x-width+1)

  def box_open(x):
      if box_list[x] == "M":
          # Checks if the block is a mine
          button_list[x].config(image=photo_mine, relief = SUNKEN)
          # Stops if it was a mine
          button_frame.destroy()
          all_code()
      elif box_list[x] == 0:
          # If there are no nearby mines, open all nearby tiles.
          open_zero(x)
      else:
          # If not a mine, change button text to the amount of nearby mines.
          button_list[x].config(text=box_list[x], bg="#90949b")
```

Hopefully you can understand my code from this snippet. It may not be possible the way I have coded it, but if anyone has any ideas, I would love to hear them. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I just finished writing a minesweeper game and I put on GitHub if you want to take a look: https://github.com/redcricket/minesweep I handled the "open zero" functionality with recursion.  I think the problem you are having in your open_zero() method is that you are not checking if the box has already been opened, so you get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **[queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))**. In Python, this may come in the form of a `list`. Use `.append()` to enqueue an item and `.pop()` to dequeue an item. (Note that you don't need to use a queue. You can use a stack or a plain list, but a queue will simulate cells spreading from the centre of the click, which may help if you have some neat animation in mind.)

```py
##  TODO check over this implementation
def is_open(x):
    return button_list[x].bg == "#90949b"


def open_zero(x):
    button_list[x].config(bg="#90949b")

    queue = [x]                     ##  init

    while queue:
        curr = queue.pop(0)         ##  dequeue cells here

        if is_open(curr):           ##  STOPPING CONDITION    [1]
            continue

        box_open(curr)

        if box_list[curr] != 0:     ##  checks if curr is a zero-cell, you've already implemented this previously 
            continue


        ##  enqueue nearby cells here

        # if curr >= width:         ##  STOPPING CONDITION(s) [2]
        queue.append(curr+1)        ##  TODO check curr isn't on the right edge
        queue.append(curr-1)        ##  TODO check curr isn't on the left edge
        queue.append(curr+width)    ##  TODO check curr isn't on the bottom edge
        queue.append(curr+width-1)  ##  ... 
        queue.append(curr+width+1)  ##  ... the rest has been left as an
        queue.append(curr-width)    ##  ... exercise for the reader
        queue.append(curr-width-1)
        queue.append(curr-width+1)

        ##  NOTE: without STOPPING CONDITION(s), recursion or the while-loop
        ##  will never terminate
        ##  except for the max-recursion depth
```

Note that, one reason why Python is upset with the recursion in your code, is that you're not providing any *stopping* or *terminating conditions*. I can't stress how important these are. I've partially-implemented one of the conditions (`is_open(x)`, which checks if cell `x` is open or not).

Since this is Minesweeper, I'm assuming you're making this on a matrix/grid (but storing buttons in a list). Still, you need to check the boundaries of the grid, or else your recursion will jump through the grid walls or do other weird things.

*(Thought experiment: Imagine me clicking on the bottom-left cell of the grid. This will trigger `box_open(x)`. This will in turn trigger `box_open(x-1)` or `queue.append(curr-1)`... but these will open up the **rightmost cell on the second row from the bottom**. This is unexpected. You need to check that the cell isn't on the left edge... before doing `box_open(x-1)`.)*

I am **highly** confident that your original code can work, but one of the important key elements of recursion (or any looping) is to provide stopping/terminating conditions. That should be everyone's main takeaway here (aside from the implementation of the queue).

Comment: Alright I will look into that. Thank you very much! I had a bunch of if statements testing where the boxes were, but I just set it to open all around for testing, so I have the code for checking the corners and sides.

Comment: Ah ok then. :-) Guess it's a bit tough deciding how minimal the question-code should be. Maybe next time have a comment e.g. `#  if-statements checking boundaries omitted for brevity` to indicate that you did consider the checks.

Comment: Yeah. I did get it to work! I did it a bit differently, but that use of a queue was necessary, so thank you very much!